# Inner Join syntax error in Alembic execute

Tags: sql, postgresql, alembic

I have a `"DevAssociation"` table with columns `prod_id` and `dev_id` where `dev_id` is a fk from `DevRun`, I would like to move `prod_id` to `DevRun` table, so I created a new column in `DevRun` called `prod_id`. Then I am doing the following SQL command to move the `prod_id` data over. I am doing this from `alembic` in Python but I feel like where it's failing is more generally related to sql.

```
    conn.execute('UPDATE "DevRun"\
         INNER JOIN "DevAssociation" \
             ON "DevAssociation".dev_id= "DevRun".id \
                 SET prod_id="DevAssociation".prod_id')
```

I get the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 1: UPDATE "DevRun" INNER JOIN "DevAssociation" O...
                             ^

[SQL: UPDATE "DevRun" INNER JOIN "DevAssociation" ON "DevAssociation".dev_id= "DevRun".id SET prod_id="DevAssociation".prod_id]
```

Any idea why? This is on postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

update in postgresql based on another table looks like this:

```
UPDATE "DevRun"
SET prod_id="DevAssociation".prod_id
FROM "DevAssociation"
WHERE "DevAssociation".dev_id= "DevRun".id
```